# I need to construct a single trigger that assigns a pilot as co-pilot when a pilot is already assigned for a charter

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS COPILOT_ASSIGNED;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER COPILOT_ASSIGNED 
    BEFORE INSERT ON crew 
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF CHAR_TRIP EXISTS AND CREW_JOB = 'Pilot'
    THEN SET NEW.CREW_JOB = 'Copilot';
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ; 

INSERT INTO crew VALUES (10019, 109, 'Pilot');
INSERT INTO crew VALUES (10019, 106, 'Pilot');

SELECT * FROM crew WHERE CHAR_TRIP = 10019;
```

I cannot determine how to write this trigger.  I need to check to see if a charter(CREW_TRIP) has already been assigned a pilot(CREW_JOB).  If so, then pilot needs to be changed to copilot(CREW_JOB).

Comment: DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS COPILOT_ASSIGNED;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER COPILOT_ASSIGNED 
 BEFORE INSERT ON crew 
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF OLD.CREW_JOB = 'Pilot'
 THEN SET NEW.CREW_JOB = 'Copilot';
 END IF;
END //
 DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS COPILOT_ASSIGNED;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER COPILOT_ASSIGNED 
    BEFORE INSERT ON crew 
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM crew WHERE CHAR_TRIP = NEW.CHAR_TRIP AND 
CREW_JOB='Pilot')
    THEN SET NEW.CREW_JOB = 'Copilot';
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ; 

INSERT INTO crew VALUES (10019, 109, 'Pilot');
INSERT INTO crew VALUES (10019, 106, 'Pilot');
```